# Unable to load a USB keyboard driver on Debian machine

Tags: debian, drivers, usb, keyboard

I have a pretty simple driver for USB keyboard:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/usb.h>
#include <linux/usb/input.h>
#include <linux/hid.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("TEST_USER");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A USB Keyboard Driver Kernel Module");

static struct usb_device_id usb_kbd_id_table[] = {
    { USB_INTERFACE_INFO(
        USB_INTERFACE_CLASS_HID,
        USB_INTERFACE_SUBCLASS_BOOT,
    USB_INTERFACE_PROTOCOL_KEYBOARD) },
    { } /* Terminating entry */
};

MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(usb, usb_kbd_id_table);

static int kbd_probe(struct usb_interface *interface,
    const struct usb_device_id *id)
{
    pr_info("USB keyboard probe function called\n");
    return 0;
}

static void kbd_disconnect(struct usb_interface *interface)
{
    pr_info("USB keyboard disconnect function called\n");
}

static struct usb_driver kbd_driver = {
    .name  = "usbkbd",
    .probe = kbd_probe,
    .disconnect = kbd_disconnect,
    .id_table = usb_kbd_id_table,
};

static int __init kbd_init(void)
{
    int res = 0;
    res = usb_register(&kbd_driver);
    if (res)
        pr_err("usb_register failed with error %d", res);
    return res;
}

static void __exit kbd_exit(void)
{
    pr_debug("USB Keyboard Removed..\n");
    usb_deregister(&kbd_driver);
    return;
}

module_init(kbd_init);
module_exit(kbd_exit);
```

I name it `kbtest.ko` and load it with `insmod kbtest.ko` and it is successfully and verified with `lsmod`. Concretely:

```
lsmod | grep "usb"
usbhid                 31758  0 
hid                    69153  2 hid_generic,usbhid
usbcore               115019  6 ohci_hcd,ohci_pci,ehci_hcd,ehci_pci,kbtest,usbhid
usb_common             12484  1 usbcore
```

So I plug in my USB keyboard but fails to execute the driver. Concretely, the probe function is not called. Here is my dmesg after the detection of keyboard:

```
[ 1219.695553] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 6 using ohci-pci
[ 1219.996010] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1267, idProduct=0103
[ 1220.016126] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[ 1220.100005] input: HID 1267:0103 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:06.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:1267:0103.0008/input/input14
[ 1220.126349] hid-generic 0003:1267:0103.0008: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [HID 1267:0103] on usb-0000:00:06.0-2/input0
[ 1220.206453] input: HID 1267:0103 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:06.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.1/0003:1267:0103.0009/input/input15
[ 1220.224334] hid-generic 0003:1267:0103.0009: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Device [HID 1267:0103] on usb-0000:00:06.0-2/input1
```

The information ends here. What exactly is the problem here? I am running Debian machine inside Virtual Box.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on my ubuntu 14.04 machine. The problem might be the default `usbhid` driver prevents your driver to function properly. That may be the reason why the `probe` is not getting invoked on hotplug. Try removing `usbhid` module. Check for `udev rules` defined by your distro, that autoloads the default `usbhid` driver module on hotplug even if you unload it.